# How to add input text and buttons to VSTS menu bar via extention

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I was playing around with VSTS extensions and one thing I was not able to find anywhere in documentation is how to add different types of elements into menubar beside of categories. 
I was wondering if there is a way to add for example `<input type="text" />` and `<button />` to get something like this

[image]

Only thing I was able to find is [MenuBar control](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/ui-controls/menubaro) but this actually adds submenu controls, which is something different, than what I am after.

Comment: This can't be achieved by now. Where do you get the screenshot, did your just PS it? :）

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for a kind of UI control like Code Search:

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no such control for now, not support. In that line, you could only [*add your custom hub*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-hub).

If you really need this feature, greet to add a related [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services). PM will kindly review your suggestion.